# My sort date return all of time value 0 using typescript

Tags: angular, sorting, typescript

I need to sort this json by date. I try to use this code, but doesn't work correctly.
My json

```
{
   "StatusCode":0,
   "StatusMessage":"OK",
   "StatusDescription":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "datetime_device":"2018-03-13T23:00:00.000Z",
         "alarmtype_id":1,
         "alarmnumber":4,
         "device_serial":"11"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "datetime_device":"2018-03-20T23:00:00.000Z",
         "alarmtype_id":2,
         "alarmnumber":5,
         "device_serial":"22"
      },
      {
         "id":"3",
         "datetime_device":"2018-03-12T23:00:00.000Z",
         "alarmtype_id":2,
         "alarmnumber":5,
         "device_serial":"33"
      },
      {
         "id":"4",
         "datetime_device":"2018-03-19T23:00:00.000Z",
         "alarmtype_id":1,
         "alarmnumber":4,
         "device_serial":"44"
      }
   ]
}
```

My ts code:

```
public dueDate: Date;
public notif: Notifications[];
getAllNotifications() {
    this.ws.NotifGetAll().subscribe(
        notif=> {
            this.notif= notif;  // show me all value in json
        }
    );
}

private getTime(date?: Date) {
    return date != null ? date.getTime() : 0;
}

public sortbydate(): void {
    this.notif.sort(() => {
        console.log(this.getTime(this.dueDate) - this.getTime(this.dueDate))
        return this.getTime(this.dueDate) - this.getTime(this.dueDate);
    });
}
```

My service:

```
  public NotifGetAll(): Observable<Notifications[]> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-access-token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.NotifGetAll), {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
          this.auth.logout();
        } else {
          return res.StatusDescription.map(notif => {
            return new Notifications(notif);
          });
        }
      });
  }
```

And Notifications class:

```
export class Notifications {
    datetime_device: Date;
    alarmtype_id: string;
    device_serial: string;
    id: string;
    alarmnumber: number;
}
```

My html code:
When I click this button, show me only 0 in console

```
<div>
    <p>Sort:</p>
    <button (click)="sortbydate()">sort by date
    </button>
</div>
```

The result is: not sort correctly and show only 0 in console.

Can you suggest me any solution please?

Thnx

Comment: You should upgrade your `angular` version to latest or at least 4, there your will have the new `httpClient` which can help you add response types and from there `TypeScript` will do his `Type inference` job and help you avoid mistakes like this.

Comment: "@angular/animations": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.3",

Comment: Great, then you should read this [Angular HttpClient Docs](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are subtracting the same `this.dueDate` value and you don't retrieve the result of the sorting. Try this:

```
public sortbydate(): void {
    this.notif = this.notif.sort((a, b) => 
        this.getTime(a.datetime_device) - this.getTime(b.datetime_device)
    );
}
```

Comment: Show this error:  TypeError: date.getTime is not a function   at AllEventsComponent.getTime

Comment: I edited my post according to your json object. Tell me if it works now

Comment: I can't use StatusDescription  in notif. I add service in my qyesitin

Answer (score 0):

It is returning 0, because you're subtracting the same value in your `sortByDate()` function.

You're subtracting `this.dueDate` by `this.dueDate`: see the code below.

```
return this.getTime(this.dueDate) - this.getTime(this.dueDate);
```

The `.sort()` function returns a sorted array, but conveniently you can use a function expression to accomplish your goal.

```
public sortbydate(): void {
    this.notif = this.notif.sort((date1, date2) => 
        return this.getTime(date1.datetime_device) - this.getTime(date2.datetime_device)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not how the sort function works. You need to declare arguments for the items that are being compared by `sort` and use them, along those lines:

```
this.notif.sort((a, b) => {
  const sort = this.getTime(a.dueDate) - this.getTime(b.dueDate) 
  console.log(sort)
  return sort;
});
```

(`dueDate` might not be the correct property, it has to exist on the item you sort. Maybe you want `datetime_device` as in your JSON?)

Comment: Yes is my mistake, I want datetime_device. I try this code, but show me TypeError: date.getTime is not a function. Thnx

Comment: Have you correctly parsed your JSON to Dates? i.e. run it through `new Date(json.datetime_device)`? You should learn how to use a debugger, set breakpoints, look at the values, etc.

Comment: I add and service in my question.

Comment: @Autonna: I do not see any date conversion, so you probably have a string containing a date.

Comment: Did you assign the value back to the property? Did you check whether the parsing worked correctly? Seriously, this is very basic stuff. You need to be able to debug stuff like this on your own.

Comment: Also, this no longer has anything to do with the sorting itself, which i already showed how to do.